# SEM vs. Hierarchical Regression

Tags: multilevel-analysis, partial-least-squares

I am comparing the outcomes of my model analysis using PLS and hierarchical regression (HR).
On SPSS (for HR), I'm using (mean or summative) scores.
On Smart-PLS, when I enter my variables as computed scores, I get very similar coefficients to HR. When I enter individual items for each latent variable, however, the figures change, including an increase in the model's total variance.

Am I supposed to get the same figures all over? Did I get something wrong? 
Do I stick to SEM with scaled latent variables?

Comment: When you say hierarchical regression, do you mean multilevel/mixed model, or variance proportioning? I think we need more details on what you did and what you found.

Comment: I mean regression in steps. First I enter the control variables, next I add my main predictors.